# Collaboration diagram is the same as class diagram in doxygen 1.8.3.1

Tags: doxygen

After upgrading to doxygen 1.8.3.1, my collaboration diagrams look the same as the class diagrams. They do not show any colllaboration at all, only derived classes etc. If I uncheck "UML_LOOK", there are no collaboration diagrams. In doxygenwizard, I've check all Dot settings.

Is this a bug or do I have something misconfigured?

Using Windows 7 64 bit, Doxygen 1.8.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exact same problem.The solution was to set the follwing defines:
Via default they are not set since 1.7.5.1

Section Build:

**EXTRACT_PRIVATE**

**EXTRACT_PACKAGE**

**EXTRACT_STATIC**

**EXTRACT_LOCALMETHODS**

Answer (score 1):

Problem still in 1.8.11, reported as
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765369